# eclipse copy resource in C project after build

Tags: eclipse, build, opencl, resourcebundle

I am working on an openCL project in eclipse CDT (latest eclipse for parallel app. developers)

I made a C project (File >> New >> C project)

After the successful build i want to copy the kernel *.cl (openCL C file) to the Debug/Release folder.
And i want the eclipse to do.

Is there any possible option for that. (Visual Studio can mark files as resource and it will copy it to there) or (Visual has post build macro)

I am newby in eclipse and programming in linux.

Please help thanks!!